# C# Using Newtonsoft.json DefaultContractResolver IValueProvider to replace Data crashes

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I am attempting to use Newtonsoft.json DefaultContractResolver to output json. When the ContractResolver finds a class of type IVariant, it sets the output based upon the IVariant's "TypeName"

Without my ContractResolver code the json would look something like this:

```
{
  "Data" :
  {
    "Aim" :
      {
        "Joystick" :
        {
          "Test" : "Test"
        }, 
        "Button" :
        {
          "Test" : "Test2"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

and with my resolver, It replaces "Aim" with either Joystick, or Button, and look like this:

```
{
  "Data" :
  {
    "Button" :
    {
      "Test" : "Test2"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the full code I used.

```
  public class JsonTester
  {
    public void Test()
    {
      var d = new Outer();

      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, new JsonSerializerSettings()
      {
        ContractResolver = new JsonContractResolver()
      });
    }
  }

  public interface IVariant
  {
    object Data { get; }

    string TypeName { get; set; }
  }

  public interface IVariantData
  {
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Variant<TEnum, TData> : IVariant where TEnum : struct where TData : class, IVariantData, new()
  {
    [DataMember]
    public TData Data { get; }

    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    object IVariant.Data => Data;

    public Variant()
    {
      Data = new TData();
    }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public sealed class VariantHolder
  {
    [DataContract]
    public class Joystick
    {
      [DataMember]
      public string Test { get; set; } = "Test";
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Button
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string Test2 { get; set; } = "Test2";
  }

    [DataContract]
    public sealed class AimΞVariant : Variant<AimΞVariant.VariantEnum, AimΞVariant.VariantData>
  {
    public AimΞVariant()
    {
      TypeName = "Button";
    }
    public enum VariantEnum : byte
    {
      Joystick,
      Button
    }

    [DataContract]
    public sealed class VariantData : IVariantData
    {
      [DataMember]
      Joystick _Joystick = new Joystick();

      [DataMember]
      Button _Button = new Button();

      public Button Button => _Button;
      public Joystick Joystick => _Joystick;
    }
  }

    [DataMember]
    AimΞVariant Aim = new AimΞVariant();
  }

  [DataContract]
  public sealed class Outer
  {
    [DataMember]
    VariantHolder Data = new VariantHolder();
  }

  public class JsonContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
  {
    public JsonContractResolver()
    {

    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
      return base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
  {
    var list = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).Select(p =>
    {
      var member = p.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>();

      return new JsonProperty()
      {
        PropertyName = p.Name,
        PropertyType = p.PropertyType,
        Readable = true,
        Writable = true,
        ValueProvider = CreateMemberValueProvider(p),
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include
      };
    }).Concat(
    type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).Select(p =>
    {
      var member = p.GetCustomAttribute<DataMemberAttribute>();
      return new JsonProperty()
      {
        PropertyName = p.Name,
        PropertyType = p.FieldType,
        Readable = true,
        Writable = true,
        ValueProvider = CreateMemberValueProvider(p),
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include
      };
    })).ToList();

    return list;
  }

    protected override IValueProvider CreateMemberValueProvider(MemberInfo member)
    {
      Type type = member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property ? ((PropertyInfo)member).PropertyType : ((FieldInfo)member).FieldType;

      if (typeof(IVariant).IsAssignableFrom(type))
      {
        return new IVariantValueProvider(member, type);
      }

      return base.CreateMemberValueProvider(member);
    }
  }

  internal class IVariantValueProvider : IValueProvider
  {
    private MemberInfo member;
    private Type type;

    public IVariantValueProvider(MemberInfo member, Type type)
    {
      this.member = member;
      this.type = type;
    }

    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
      IVariant variant;
      
      switch (member)
      {
      case PropertyInfo p:
        variant = (IVariant)p.GetValue(target);
        break;
      case FieldInfo f:
        variant = (IVariant)f.GetValue(target);
        break;
      default:
        throw new InvalidCastException();
      }

      var dataType = variant.TypeName;

      var property = variant.Data.GetType().GetProperty(dataType);

      var value = property.GetValue(variant.Data);

      return value;
    }

    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
```

The code crashes somewhere inside JsonConvert.SeralizeObject.

> ```
> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error getting value from 'Data' on 'Iugo.Test.VariantHolder+Button'.'
>
> Inner Exception: InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Button' to type 'Iugo.Test.Variant`2[Iugo.Test.VariantHolder+AimΞVariant+VariantEnum,Iugo.Test.VariantHolder+AimΞVariant+VariantData]'.
> ```

Comment: You've asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473008/c-sharp-using-ivalueprovider-in-newtonsoft-json-to-change-item-in-lists-name) already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your `InvalidCastException` here: [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hq1XEU).

The cause of the exception is that you are setting a custom [`JsonProperty.ValueProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_ValueProvider.htm) that returns some nested object -- but you are not updating [`JsonProperty.PropertyType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_PropertyType.htm) to be assignable from the type actually returned.  Later, during serialization, Json.NET assumes that the value returned by the value provider is in fact compatible with the property type -- and throws an exception when this is not the case.

You will thus need to update `JsonProperty.PropertyType` to be consistent with the value actually returned, but since this is not actually known at compile time, you can assign the property type to be `typeof(object)` to indicate that any type can be returned.

A simplified version of your `JsonContractResolver` that does this is as follows:

```
public class JsonContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (typeof(IVariant).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
        {
            property.ValueProvider = new IVariantValueProvider(member, property.PropertyType);
            property.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
            // The following fixes the InvalidCastException.  PropertyType has to be assignable from the type actually returned.
            // Since we don't know that at compile time, we need to set it to typeof(object).
            property.PropertyType = typeof(object);
        }
        return property;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var list = type.GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).Select(p =>
        {
            return CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization);
        }).Concat(
        type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public).Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes().Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(DataMemberAttribute))).Select(p =>
        {
            return CreateProperty(p, memberSerialization);
        })).ToList();

        return list;
    }
}
```

Demo fix here: [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pDvuJf).

With this fix, you will get the following JSON, which is closer to what you want, but not exactly correct:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Aim": {
      "Test2": "Test2"
    }
  }
}
```

I.e. `"Aim"` has not been renamed to `"Button"`.  That's because you are modifying the *value provider* for the `Aim` property, which cannot possibly modify the name of the property itself.  In fact, Json.NET has no built-in mechanism to modify a property name in runtime.  For some options to do this manually, see:

- [How to change property names depending on the type when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44577850/3744182) which suggests using a custom `JsonConverter`.  (If you cannot modify your classes, your `JsonContractResolver` could add the converter itself.)
- [Newtonsoft JSON dynamic property name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37917164/3744182).
- [How to serialize runtime added "properties" to Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46888732/3744182) (which uses a different approach than the first two, and hooks into the extension data mechanism.)