# JsonConvert replace serialized non-object values with type names

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to use Newtonsoft's JsonConvert.SerializeObject, except I want to switch each value into its type name whilst still ensuring any objects or arrays are accounted for.

As an example I would be looking to convert this:

```
{
    "organisationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "submittedAt": "2023-05-08T21:58:50+00:00",
    "multiple": [
        123
    ],
    "obj": {
        "innerEx1": "hello world",
        "innerEx2": 123
    }
}
```

into this:

```
{
    "organisationId": "Guid",
    "submittedAt": "DateTimeOffset",
    "multiple": [
        "int"
    ],
    "obj": {
        "innerEx1": "string",
        "innerEx2": "int"
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've had no luck yet!

Comment: You could use a custom contract resolver + `IValueProvider` to replace selected property values by declared property type.  See e.g. [C# Using Newtonsoft.json DefaultContractResolver IValueProvider to replace Data crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64476076/3744182).  Do you know the exact property types you need to replace?  In the example shown you're replacing `int`, `string`, `Guid`, and `DateTimeOffset` but not the root object itself nor `"obj"`.

Comment: So it's for API documentation so the types could vary, but generally it's just int, string, datetimeoffset/datetime, bool and guid each of which can be nullable.

Comment: And also arrays/lists/collections/etc of the same?  And what about dictionaries?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I've tried a few different solutions including the DefaultContractResolver to no avail so far but I'll play around with the link you provided and see if I can figure it out from that.

The only objects that should have their types converted are non-complex ones that have basic values like guid/string/etc, all others should follow the default Json format

Comment: I think a single `JsonConverter` (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)  could probably do the trick but it would take me a bit to write it out and QC. But you could look into that and see if it's what you need.

Comment: It's not even clear you should be doing this by serializing a class instance.  It might be better to do it directly from the contract returned by the contract resolver.

Comment: Alright @EmperorEto I'll take a look now as well, thanks

Comment: @dbc good point. Or even just reflecting through the class and spitting out the JSON yourself. I'm never above doing things like that when it's extremely bespoke.

Comment: @dbc Interesting, I haven't looked at Json serialization very much so wouldn't know for sure

Comment: @EmperorEto ahh yeah I began doing that and figured I would try and see if there is a slightly easier approach, but given how complex it seems to be when I've looked around it might just be easier to do something like that

Comment: so are you trying to replace strong types to stings ? maby custom JsonConverter might help

Comment: I think he's looking to build some kind of schema definition essentially, right? I did something similar awhile back for making Typescript definition files for my server-side POCOs. (I'm sure there were prebuilt canned solutions but I'm a prima donna and have to do it all myself). I did wind up doing recursive reflection but it was a little tricky honoring the `JsonProperty` attribute. But if you don't have anything too complicated it shouldn't be bad. Plus then you'll have it and own it forever.

Comment: use https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/SampleJsonSchemaGenerator to create jsonschema . something like var schema = NJsonSchema.JsonSchema.FromSampleJson(json);
 var schemaJson = schema.ToJson().Dump();